# Clipping extent using QGIS is not matching shape only small sections

Tags: qgis, raster, clip

I am new here, and I am working with QGIS 3.16.9.
I have a shapefile and a raster. I am trying to clip the raster by mask layer, but it only cuts some pixels, not the whole shape.

[image]

And if I clip the raster by extent, there is a small section of the shapefile that is not covered by the new clipped raster.

[image]

Every pixel is 5km. Do you have any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: seems pretty normal to me ... there is just a white pixel in there, it leaves the pixels that have more than 50% of them intersecting with shape

Comment: try adding a 2.5km buffer to the shapes